# Convert InputString to String as if program don't hangs

Tags: java, serial-port, inputstream

My program can run with `inputStream.toString();` but as you know thats not a good way to convert `inputStream` to `String`. So when I try to convert properly it hangs.
My methods are:

```
    private void jButton2ActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                         

    if(initialized && connected){
        try{
            sms.findOperator();
            jTextArea2.append(sms.logString);
            sms.logString = "";
        }
        catch(Exception e){
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Failed to find operator!", "ERROR", JOptionPane.ERROR_MESSAGE);
        }
    }
    else JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Cannot connect to the port specified!", "ERROR", JOptionPane.ERROR_MESSAGE);
    // TODO add your handling code here:
}
```

This is the `findOperator()` method:

```
    public void findOperator(){  
        send("AT+COPS?\r\n");
}
```

Here is `send()` method:

```
    public void send(String cmd) {
    try {
        //Thread.sleep(200);
        outputStream.flush();
        outputStream.write(cmd.getBytes());
        inputStream = serialPort.getInputStream();
        //System.out.println(" Input Stream... " + inputStream.toString());
        Thread.sleep(300);

        logString += inputStreamtoString(inputStream);
    }
    catch(Exception e){
        e.printStackTrace();            
    }
    finally{

        //logString += inputStream.toString()+ '\n';
//            if(infoType == "msg") return "Input Stream... " + inputStream.toString()+     '\n';
//            else return inputStream.toString();    
        //return logString;
        //logString += inputStreamtoString(inputStream);
    }

}
```

And this is the `inputStreamtoString()` method:

```
    public String inputStreamtoString(InputStream is) throws IOException{
//        try {
//            return new java.util.Scanner(is).useDelimiter("\\A").next();
//        } catch (java.util.NoSuchElementException e) {
//            return "";
//        }        

    BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(is)); 
    StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder(); 

    String line = null; 

    try { 
        while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) { 
        sb.append(line + "\n"); 
        } 
    } catch (IOException e) { 
        e.printStackTrace(); 
    } finally { 
        try { 
        is.close(); 
        } catch (IOException e) { 
        e.printStackTrace(); 
        } 
    }

    return sb.toString(); 
}
```

If I don't use `inputStreamtoString()` method and use `inputStream.toString()` my program runs well, but I don't get proper String. Any suggestion?
Thanks in advance...

**Update:** My modem uses the port `COM3` with a GSM SIM card. I get a String containing huge space, like:

```
+COPS:                  <...500 spaces...>                    0,0,"Banglalink"
```

So I hate that spaces. I need a string : `+COPS: 0,0,"Banglalink"`

Comment: As i said in my comment to the answer below:  
Do **not** use `new String(bytes[])`, do **not** use `string.getBytes()`, do **not** use `new InputStreamReader(InputStream)`, and do **not** use `new OutputStreamWriter(OutputStream)`. They use the platform default encoding, which is equivalent to depending on a **global variable with an essentially random value**. *Specify* the encoding you are using unless you want your program to break randomly in an inexplicable manner at some unpredictable point in the future on some other platform or for some other user.

Comment: Also, `InputStream.toString()` can't and won't do what you expect it to do, for the same reason, so don't use it.

Comment: Further, i want to warn you about `BufferedReader.readLine()`, which corrupts the input by throwing away line endings. You can't know whether you got `"\r"`, `"\n"`, `"\r\n"`, or end of input. I recommend against using it, except for the simplest cases where line endings are guaranteed not to be important.

Answer (score 1):

You are trying to read exhaustively (that is until all data is read) from a stream that is connected to a serial port.  This will hang if there is no data available on the port (waiting for data to come).  Even if there is data, you will have an infinite loop.

UPDATE:
You could try something like this instead (adapted from code listed [here](http://www.java2s.com/Code/JavaAPI/javax.comm/CommPortgetInputStream.htm)):

```
 byte[] readBuffer = new byte[200];

 try {
   while (is.available() > 0) {
     int numBytes = is.read(readBuffer);
     sb.append(new String(readBuffer, "US-ASCII"));
   }
 } catch (IOException e) {
   // handle exception
 }
```

UPDATE: chaged the string creation to use a specified charset (instead of the system default)

Comment: I tried this code too `public String inputStreamtoString(InputStream is) throws IOException{            try {
                return new java.util.Scanner(is).useDelimiter("\\A").next();
            } catch (java.util.NoSuchElementException e) {
                return "";
            }
    }` but same thing happns :(

Comment: No hang, but still not a perfect String. Same thing as `inputStream.toString()`.

Comment: Do **not** use `new String(bytes[])`, do **not** use `string.getBytes()`, do **not** use `new InputStreamReader(InputStream)`, and do **not** use `new OutputStreamWriter(OutputStream)`. They use the platform default encoding, which is equivalent to depending on a **global variable with an essentially random value**. *Specify* the encoding you are using unless you want your program to break randomly in an inexplicable manner at some unpredictable point in the future on some other platform or for some other user.

Comment: @ChristofferHammarström - you are right.  I don't normally parse byte arrays to create Strings, nevertheless, should have suspected a possible encoding problem

Comment: @CoolBrain - Can you update your question with what is being put into the serial port (if you can), what you expect to get out, and what you actually get out (via .toString(), for example)?

Comment: As I understand, my suggested solution works well: it does not hang and you get the string that is actually sent to you.  Do you control what is being sent?  It seems the sender inserts a lot of spaces for some reason.  You need to figure out why that is happening and fix it if you can.  Alternatively, if the difference is always that you get extra spaces, you can use simple `string.replace()` to get rid of unwanted spaces.

Comment: How did you use `String.replace()`?  It is also possible you get data that is not space